# What config file does openstack Poppy use? & How to log the debug info when poppy running?

Tags: python, logging, configuration, cdn, openstack

- Poppy means this project: https://github.com/openstack/poppy

I'm trying to run Poppy project on my CentOS 7.0, following the README on github site. It did run when i typed `poppy-server` on the command line, and i could get response when i request with `curl --include --request  GET --header "Content-Type: application/json"  -H 'X-Auth-Token:000' -H 'X-Project-ID:000' http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1.0/health`.

Following the README, i duplicated file `poppy.conf` and `logging.conf` to the `.poppy` folder, which is in the same hierarchy with `poppy` projcet folder.

Then the problems came: the configuration in `poppy.conf` doesn't work at all! Even when i changed the name of `poppy.conf` to `poppy.conf.backup`, poppy-server can run as well. So i tried to find the log file to see what's wrong. Unfortunately, `poppy.log` file could not be found in the system, nor `server.log` name file configured in `poppy.conf`.

I've googled a lot and tried all i can do to solve this problem. Only found that, using `poppy-server --debug -v command` can print out the debug info on the terminal, and the default configuration of storage and provider are in the boot file `poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py`.

But I still have no idea on which config file poppy use and how to log poppy info.

Any help would be appreciated.

- here's the output of `poppy-server --debug -v` command:

  [root@localhost ~]# poppy-server --debug -v
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.447 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] init bootstrap **init** /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:79
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.447 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] loading transport transport /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:176
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.448 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] Loading manager driver manager /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:152
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.448 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] Loading storage driver storage /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:129
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.506 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('mockdb = poppy.storage.mockdb:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.524 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('cassandra = poppy.storage.cassandra:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.524 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] Loading provider extension(s) provider /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:109
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.525 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('fastly = poppy.provider.fastly:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.525 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('mock = poppy.provider.mock:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.527 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('cloudfront = poppy.provider.cloudfront:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.527 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('akamai = poppy.provider.akamai:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.527 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('maxcdn = poppy.provider.maxcdn:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.527 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] Loading DNS driver dns /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:85
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.528 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('default = poppy.dns.default:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.529 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('rackspace = poppy.dns.rackspace:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.529 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('designate = poppy.dns.designate:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.530 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] loading distributed task distributed_task /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:201
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.530 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] Loading distributed_task driver: taskflow distributed_task /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:210
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.530 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('taskflow = poppy.distributed_task.taskflow:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.546 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('default = poppy.manager.default:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.906 25550 DEBUG poppy.bootstrap [-] Loading transport driver: pecan transport /home/leoncai/poppy/poppy/bootstrap.py:184
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.907 25550 DEBUG stevedore.extension [-] found extension EntryPoint.parse('pecan = poppy.transport.pecan:Driver') _load_plugins /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py:156
  2015-12-03 16:08:39.909 25550 INFO poppy.transport.pecan.driver [-] Serving on host 127.0.0.1:8888

Answer (score 0):

The config file problem was solved by my elder colleague. May be not the prefect solution, but the project works well. Here's what he did:
edit the bootstrap.py under the 'poppy/poppy/' directory, add the following two lines of code:
config_file = ''
cfg.CONF(args=[], default_config_files=[config_file])

then restart the poppy-server and poppy-worker process.

The 'log' problem remains unsolved for now.